# What do we know about G.F. Handel as pedagogue?

Tags: teaching

From Bach we know that he was a wanted teacher and his keyboard work is a great deal of teaching composition and counterpoint.

So I ask myself is there something similar know about G.F. Händel - as I know just his great choral and orchestral works.

I have just a collection with some little fantasias that might be written for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Handel did have students. He wrote some exercises in counterpoint for them. Apparently little is known about his students. There is a (behind a paywall) article: "Handel's students, two lovers and a shipwreck," by David Hunter. It's an intriguing title, perhaps for a movie like "Titanic." The only student I have actually read about was Princess Anne. Some exercises she did are available. Alfred Mann's booke "The Great Composer as Teacher and Student," does have a bit about Handel.

Answer (score -1):

Continuo Playing According to Handel: His Figured Bass Exercises (Oxford Early Music Series)

According to ttw that’s all what I’ve found:

https://www.slideshare.net/fitrah67563/continuo-playing-according-to-handel-his-figured-bass-exercises-oxford-early-music-series-109183350
[enter link description here](https://www.slideshare.net/fitrah67563/continuo-playing-according-to-handel-his-figured-bass-exercises-oxford-early-music-series-109183350)
*This book is an edition, with commentary, of Handel's exercises for continuo playing, which he wrote for the daughters of George II. The exercises, which until now have not been readily available, are supplemented by clear and concise commentary. Remaining faithful to his source, Ledbetter, who lectures in keyboard studies, has prepared an edition that will prove invaluable to students and performers of the music of Handel and his contemporaries.*